# Random variables expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, correlation, variance

Let $X, X′$ be independent random variables taking values $\pm1$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $0\le r \le 1$ and set:

$\ Y = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         X & \mbox{with probability $r$}\\
        X' & \mbox{with probability $1-r$}.\end{array} \right.  $

Find $\rho(X, Y ) = \frac{E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$.

---

My attempt: $E[X]=E[X']=0$, $Var(X)=Var(X')=1$, $E[Y]=E[X] r + E[X'] (1-r) = 0$, $E[Y^2]= X^2 r + X'^2 (1-r)=r+(1-r)=1$ so $Var[Y]=1$. So all boils down to finding $E[XY]$ which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods.  One is to look at the joint distribution

```
  X  X'   Y  XY    Prob
 +1  +1  +1  +1    1/4
 +1  -1  +1  +1    r/4
 +1  -1  -1  -1  (1-r)/4  
 -1  +1  +1  -1  (1-r)/4
 -1  +1  -1  +1    r/4
 -1  -1  -1  +1    1/4
```

which gives $E[XY]= r$. As a check, this is clearly correct when $r=0$ or $1$

Answer (score 2):

We can write $Y=BX+(1-B)X'$ where $B,X,X'$ are independent and $B\sim\mathsf{Bernoulli}(r)$.

Then: $$\mathbb EXY=\mathbb E[BX^2+(1-B)XX']$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see, you expressed $Y$ as a sum of independent r.v's, so the expectation of the RHS can be now simply calculated.

Comment: Independence does not really matter where it concerns summation. It is **always** true that $\mathbb E(U+V)=\mathbb EU+\mathbb EV$. Independence only plays a role in finding the two terms. E.g. $\mathbb EBX^2=\mathbb EB\times\mathbb EX^2=r\times1=r$